# Saving Image with the actual scale gotten from image cropping tool

Tags: php, image, image-scaling

I am trying to save image the same way it look on cropping tool, using the coping i got something like this `X = 443` and `Y = 180` and `Width = 180` and `height = 180`, now my problem is how to send it to php to resize the original image as the image editor showed using the above information. Currently am using the below php code to resize image with and height but to add X and Y is what has been giving me problem.

```
<?php
function CroppedThumbnail($imagename, $path, $width, $height, $rename, $imgQuality, $ratio=false){
    $url = '';
    $info = pathinfo($imagename);
    $newpath = $path;
    $cdn_newpath = 'cdn/';
     //Rename the image
    if($rename == true){ $newFileName = $newpath . '/' . substr($info['filename'],0,5) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.jpeg';}
    else{ $newFileName = $newpath . '/' . $imagename;}

    $imageAvatar =  substr($info['filename'],0,5) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.jpeg';
    if(!file_exists($cdn_newpath.$newpath)){
        mkdir($cdn_newpath.$newpath, 0777, true);
        chmod($cdn_newpath.$newpath, 0755);
    }
    if(is_dir($cdn_newpath.$newpath . '/') && file_exists($cdn_newpath.$newFileName)){ return $url . $newFileName;}
    else{
   // Resample
    if ($info['extension'] == 'jpeg' OR $info['extension'] == 'jpg'){ $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagename);}
    else if ($info['extension'] == 'gif'){ $image = imagecreatefromgif($imagename);}
    else if ($info['extension'] == 'png'){ $image = imagecreatefrompng($imagename);}

    $widthx = imagesx( $image );
    $heighty = imagesy( $image );

    // calculate thumbnail size
    if($ratio == true){
       $new_width = $width;
       $new_height = floor( $heighty * ( $width / $widthx ) );
       $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
       imagecopyresampled( $image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $widthx, $heighty );
    }else{
      $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $widthx, $heighty);
    }
    imagejpeg($image_p, $cdn_newpath.$newFileName); 
    return $url . $newFileName;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing same problem as I had faced. See below code snippet which I have extracted from my class. Some of the code will look pseudo code to you.

```
$trueFactorx = $original_height/$current_height;
$trueFactory = $original_width/$current_width;

// calls to my wrapper functions
$img=image_crop($img,$crop_cordinates,$trueFactorx,$trueFactory);
save_image($img,$image_type,$new_image_path);

function image_crop($img1,$crop_cordinates,$factorX,$factorY)
{ 
    $corrdinate_array=explode(",", $crop_cordinates);
    $x=$corrdinate_array[0] * $factorX;
    $y=$corrdinate_array[1]* $factorY;
    $height=$corrdinate_array[2]* $factorY;
    $width=$corrdinate_array[3]* $factorX;
    $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopy($img2, $img1, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height);
    return $img2;
}


function save_image($img,$image_type,$new_image_path)
{
    switch(strtolower($image_type))
    {
        case 'png':
            header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
            imagepng($img,$new_image_path);
        break;
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($img,$new_image_path);
        break;
    case 'jpeg':
        imagejpeg($img,$new_image_path);
        break;
    case 'jpg':
        imagejpeg($img,$new_image_path);
    break;
    default:
        die('Unsupported File!'); 
    }


    imagedestroy($img);

}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Please can you explain a bit how to pass my X,Y,width and height to your function?

Comment: Thank you for attempting my question actually your function didn't work but this line fixed my own function ` imagecopy($img2, $img1, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height);`